# Slow Doctrine pagination when joining

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, pagination

My table structure contains a lot of tables which are in relation with the user table:

```
user
user_mails
user_addresses
user_phonenumbers
[...]
```

So a user can have as many mails, addresses, phone numbers as he wants to. There's an extensive search form to search members, including joined values from the other tables; for example it's possible to search for a users address or his phone number.

To make it possible to search for values in other tables I'm joining all related tables when searching a user.

Since some users have a decent amount of data this means the amount of rows from the query is around ~30k.  Actually that's no problem, the query is executed in < 1 second, which is totally fine.

It starts getting weird as soon as the `Paginator` component comes into play. My repository method looks similar to this:

```
// User Repository
public function findUserByCriteria($criteria, $offset, $limit) {
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');

    $qb->leftJoin('u.emails', 'e')->addSelect('u');
    $qb->leftJoin('u.addresses', 'adr')->addSelect('adr');
    $qb->leftJoin('u.phonenumbers', 'phn')->addSelect('phn');
    // 4 more joins

    // ...
    // the actual search implementation goes here...
    // ....

    $qb->setFirstResult($offset);
    $qb->setMaxResults($limit);

    return new Paginator($qb, true);
}
```

The problem seems to come from the second argument of the `Paginator` constructor, `fetchJoinCollection`. As long as it's on `true` it takes around ~10s to find some users (those with a lot of data), while it just takes around ~1s when it's on `false`. The problem when it's set to `false` is that the entire pagination is messed up.

I've found out that getting rid of the joins at the top of the method also decreases execution time to around ~1s, but then it's no longer possible to search within these tables.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to avoid use `Paginator`, it is a pain with large amount of data.

In that cases I do the next: Firstly I calculate the total of data (COUNT) and use that value for my pagination and secondly I get the data with the query.

This example is using DQL instead of Query builder but you can get the idea:

```
$countDql = "SELECT COUNT (e.id)
             FROM YourBundle:Entity e
             WHERE e.condition = :yourCondition";

$dataDql = "SELECT e
             FROM YourBundle:Entity e
             WHERE e.condition = :yourCondition";

$total = $em->createQuery($countDql)->getSingleScalarResult(); //Add also  setParameter() if needed
$data = $em->createQuery($dataDql)->getResult();
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Joins are heavy, and Left Joins are even heavier.

You could change your `findUserByCriteria` method to add the joins as they are needed according to the `$criteria` argument. If there's no criteria for address for example, you don't need to join with the `Address` entity.

And if your queries are still way too slow, you can directly use PDO to create them, which is faster than using the querybuilder or DQL.

Comment: I'm actually joining as needed, just left that out for simplicity. But in case of someone searching for everything located in other tables the query gets the same as stated. The join statement itself isn't that slow - it seems like to have something to do with pagination.

Comment: When you removed your joins you got the results in ~1s, so they are probably related. And yes, the Paginator performs additional queries like stated in the docs  http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html. I would try using DQL (which seems faster than querybuilder) and if still slow, PDO. This article may help aswell https://tideways.io/profiler/blog/5-doctrine-orm-performance-traps-you-should-avoid

Comment: I've found out that the problem is NOT the query, but the returned object, since I'm iterating through the result. This object has a few hundred mbytes which makes everything pretty slow... currently trying to figure out how to optimize that.

Comment: @nehalist Why don't you query for the fields you need instead of iterating trough the objects? This way you can avoid performance loss in the hydration process.